# Elegant Regex Use in Control Structure

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I'm looking for a more elegant way to use regexes in a control structure. I want to be able to perform operations using a match without declaring the regex outside of where it is needed or having to perform a the match operation twice.

Here is my code edited for brevity:

```
/* I'm not a fan of declaring this outside of where it will be used */
var regexYoutube = new RegExp(/((youtube\.com\/watch\?v=)|(youtu\.be\/))(.{11})/i);

if(isImage(content)){
    data.type = 'IMAGE';
    data.content = toImage(content);
    postContent(data);
} else if (isVideo(content)){
    data.type = 'VIDEO';
    data.content = getVideoThumb(content);
    postContent(data);
} else {
    data.type = 'STRING';
    data.content = content;
    postContent(data);
}

function isImage(content){
    if(content.indexOf(".jpg") > -1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

function isVideo(content){
    return regexYoutube.test(content);
}

function getVideoThumb(content){
    /* I don't want to perform a test followed by an exec */
    var youtubeMatch = regexYoutube.exec(content);
    return "http://img.youtube.com/vi/"+youtubeMatch[4]+"/0.jpg";
}
```

I am away this is very nit-picky, but I will accept it if it is a necessary evil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd modify the `isVideo` function to be something else, such as `execYouTubeRegex`, and return the value of the .exec. Then instead of declaring the regex outside the `execYouTubeRegex`, declare it inside the function.

Then you can replace `isYoutube` with a call to `execYouTubeRegex` and checking if it returned anything, and replace the exec call you use elsewhere with a use of the same function.

This is a sort of evil in its own way since it uses the side effect of a function for something else (the return value for a simple is check). But it is an alternative to defining the regex in a place it is not used.

Which as mentioned in a comment, is not really all that evil. Keep your scopes small and it won't get too confusing - the code is pretty readable to me as is.